# Novice programmer trying to make a Java restaurant Menu

Tags: java, menu, project

I'm trying to make a menu for a homework assignment for my computer science course. I thought I had everything down, but I keep getting errors that I can't seem to fix. Also I can only use up to Java 1.4.2, so I can't use Scanner. Here is the code:

UPDATED CODE

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class JavaBurger
{
    static ArrayList MenuItems = new ArrayList();
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        InputStreamReader inp = null;
        BufferedReader input = null;
        int nOption  = 0;
    double price = 0;
    double amount;
    double amount1 = 0;
    double amount2 = 0;
    double amount3 = 0;
    double amount4 = 0;
    double amount5 = 0;
    double amount6 = 0;
    double amount7 = 0;
    double amount8 = 0;
    double amount9 = 0;
    double amount10 = 0;
    amount = (amount1 + amount2 + amount3 + amount4 + amount5 + amount6 + amount7 + amount8 + amount9 + amount10);
        try
        {
            inp = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
            input = new BufferedReader(inp);
            while(true)
            {
        System.out.println("Choose a Menu Option");
                System.out.println("1. Burger - 13.49");
                System.out.println("2. Pasta - 16.79");
                System.out.println("3. Salad - 13.49");
                System.out.println("4. Salmon - 18.99");
                System.out.println("5. Chicken - 16.99");
                System.out.println("6. Nachos - 13.99");
        System.out.println("7. Soup - 6.99");
        System.out.println("8. Fajitas - 18.49");
        System.out.println("9. Ribs - 23.99");
        System.out.println("10. Calamari-9.99");
                System.out.println("\nChoose an option(1-10) >> ");
        System.out.println("Subtotal: $" + amount);
        System.out.println("Total: $" + (amount * 1.13));
                nOption = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());

                switch(nOption)
                {
                    case 1:
                        Burger(input);
                        break;
            case 2:
                        Pasta(input);
                        break;
            case 3:
                        Salad(input);
                        break;
            case 4:
                        Salmon(input);
                        break;
            case 5:
                        Chicken(input);
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        Nachos(input);
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        Soup(input);
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        Fajitas(input);
                        break;
                    case 9:
                        Ribs(input);
                        break;
                    case 10:
                        Calamari(input);
                        break;

                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception exp)
        {
        }
    }

    public static void Burger(BufferedReader input) throws IOException
    {

        while(true)
        {

            System.out.println("How many Burgers would you like? ");
        int a = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());
        int aa = a.nextInt();
        double aaa = Math.pow(1 + a, aa);
            amount1 = (aaa * 13.49);


                break;
        }
    }

     public static void Pasta(BufferedReader input) throws IOException
    {
        while(true)
        {

            System.out.println("How many orders of Pasta would you like? ");
        int b = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());
        int bb = b.nextInt();
        double bbb = Math.pow(1 + b, bb);
            amount2 = (bbb * 16.79);


                break;
        }
    } public static void Salad(BufferedReader input) throws IOException
    {
        while(true)
        {

            System.out.println("How many Salads would you like? ");
        int c = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());
        int cc = c.nextInt();
        double ccc = Math.pow(1 + c, cc);
            amount3 = (ccc * 13.49);


                break;
        }
    } public static void Salmon(BufferedReader input) throws IOException
    {

        while(true)
        {

            System.out.println("How many orders of Salmon would you like? ");
        int d = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());
        int dd = d.nextInt();
        double ddd = Math.pow(1 + d, dd);
            amount4 = (ddd * 18.99);


                break;
        }
    } public static void Chicken(BufferedReader input) throws IOException
    {

        while(true)
        {

            System.out.println("How many orders of Chicken would you like? ");
        int e = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());
        int ee = e.nextInt();
        double eee = Math.pow(1 + e, ee);
            amount5 = (eee * 16.99);


                break;
        }
    } public static void Nachos(BufferedReader input) throws IOException
    {

        while(true)
        {

            System.out.println("How many orders of Nachos would you like? ");
        int f = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());
        int ff = f.nextInt();
        double fff = Math.pow(1 + f, ff);
            amount6 = (fff * 13.99);


                break;
        }
    } public static void Soup(BufferedReader input) throws IOException
    {
        while(true)
        {

            System.out.println("How many orders of Soup would you like? ");
        int g = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());
        int gg = g.nextInt();
        double ggg = Math.pow(1 + g, gg);
            amount7 = (ggg * 6.99);


                break;
        }
    } public static void Fajitas(BufferedReader input) throws IOException
    {

        while(true)
        {

            System.out.println("How many orders of 2 Fajitas would you like? ");
        int h = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());
        int hh = h.nextInt();
        double hhh = Math.pow(1 + h, hh);
            amount8 = (hhh * 18.49);


                break;
        }
    } public static void Ribs(BufferedReader input) throws IOException
    {

        while(true)
        {

            System.out.println("How many racks of Ribs would you like? ");
        int i = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());
        int ii = i.nextInt();
        double iii = Math.pow(1 + i, ii);
            amount9 = (iii * 23.99);


                break;
        }
    } public static void Calamari(BufferedReader input) throws IOException
    {

        while(true)
        {

            System.out.println("How many orders of Calamari would you like? ");
        int j = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());
        int jj = j.nextInt();
        double jjj = Math.pow(1 + j, jj);
            amount10 = (jjj * 9.99);


                break;
        }
    }
    }
```

UPDATED ERRORS:

```
C:\Java\bin>javac JavaBurger.java
JavaBurger.java:98: error: int cannot be dereferenced
            int aa = a.nextInt();
                      ^
JavaBurger.java:100: error: cannot find symbol
            amount1 = (aaa * 13.49);
            ^
  symbol:   variable amount1
  location: class JavaBurger
JavaBurger.java:114: error: int cannot be dereferenced
            int bb = b.nextInt();
                      ^
JavaBurger.java:116: error: cannot find symbol
            amount2 = (bbb * 16.79);
            ^
  symbol:   variable amount2
  location: class JavaBurger
JavaBurger.java:128: error: int cannot be dereferenced
            int cc = c.nextInt();
                      ^
JavaBurger.java:130: error: cannot find symbol
            amount3 = (ccc * 13.49);
            ^
  symbol:   variable amount3
  location: class JavaBurger
JavaBurger.java:143: error: int cannot be dereferenced
            int dd = d.nextInt();
                      ^
JavaBurger.java:145: error: cannot find symbol
            amount4 = (ddd * 18.99);
            ^
  symbol:   variable amount4
  location: class JavaBurger
JavaBurger.java:158: error: int cannot be dereferenced
            int ee = e.nextInt();
                      ^
JavaBurger.java:160: error: cannot find symbol
            amount5 = (eee * 16.99);
            ^
  symbol:   variable amount5
  location: class JavaBurger
JavaBurger.java:173: error: int cannot be dereferenced
            int ff = f.nextInt();
                      ^
JavaBurger.java:175: error: cannot find symbol
            amount6 = (fff * 13.99);
            ^
  symbol:   variable amount6
  location: class JavaBurger
JavaBurger.java:187: error: int cannot be dereferenced
            int gg = g.nextInt();
                      ^
JavaBurger.java:189: error: cannot find symbol
            amount7 = (ggg * 6.99);
            ^
  symbol:   variable amount7
  location: class JavaBurger
JavaBurger.java:202: error: int cannot be dereferenced
            int hh = h.nextInt();
                      ^
JavaBurger.java:204: error: cannot find symbol
            amount8 = (hhh * 18.49);
            ^
  symbol:   variable amount8
  location: class JavaBurger
JavaBurger.java:217: error: int cannot be dereferenced
            int ii = i.nextInt();
                      ^
JavaBurger.java:219: error: cannot find symbol
            amount9 = (iii * 23.99);
            ^
  symbol:   variable amount9
  location: class JavaBurger
JavaBurger.java:232: error: int cannot be dereferenced
            int jj = j.nextInt();
                      ^
JavaBurger.java:234: error: cannot find symbol
            amount10 = (jjj * 9.99);
            ^
  symbol:   variable amount10
  location: class JavaBurger
20 errors
```

Comment: Why do you start with a complex task like this? To me it seems that you should start with the basics (e.g. you declared `amount` twice). Try to understand the compiler errors... and it helps to properly format your code

Comment: Public class JavaBurger is oddly prophetic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Errors:

You are using `null` variables:

```
double amount;
double amount1;
```

None of these are initialized with any value. They are all `null`. You can inline the definition and give them all proper values.

```
double amount = 0, amount1 = 2, amount3 = 5;//etc
```

You are defining amount twice:

```
double amount; 
double amount = (amount1 + amount2 + amount3 + amount4 + amount5 + amoun
t6 + amount7 + amount8 + amount9 + amount10);
```

Remove the `double` from the second one:

```
amount = (amount1 + amount2 + amount3 + amount4 + amount5 + amoun
t6 + amount7 + amount8 + amount9 + amount10);
```

Next, you always need to cast from `String` to `Double`.

```
(input.readLine() * 18.49); // should be
Double.parseDouble(input.readLine()) * 18.49;
```

The `readLine()` method does not return a numeric value.

Comment: He also uses his amount*n* variables uninitialised.

Comment: thanks, that fixed a lot of errors. Now I only having errors where variables cant be found.

Comment: Updated the code and errors

Answer (score 0):

You try to declare `amount` twice:

```
double amount;
double amount1;
[...]
double amount = (amount1 + amount[...]
```

remove the `double` from the last line to make it just an assignment.

```
amount1 = (input.readInt * 13.49);
```

BufferedReader has no `readInt` method. You might want to replace this with

```
amount1 = (Integer.parseInt(input.readLine) * 13.49);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring your amounts as global variables outside the main method. What the `cannot find symbol` error means is the program can't access the variables you're telling it to access.

Also, you might want to try updating the total amount after you update the original amounts in each method.

Comment: Instead of doing `amount = amount1+amount2+amount3...` at the beginning (since the were null in your original post, although I hope you've changed them to initially be 0), when you update each amount (eg `amount1 = aaa*13.49`) add a line that does `amount = amount+amount1;` or `amount+=amount1` for short.

Comment: I'm still getting a ton of "error: cannot find symbol" for the amount variables 1-10

Comment: Did you move the amount variable declarations above the main method? Can you post your updated code/error log (keep the originals too).

Comment: I didn't change the position of variable declarations. Where do I put it to make it global?

Comment: Where you have your `ArrayList MenuItems`. If you declare the variable within the class but outside a method the variable is global. Otherwise it's local to that method. It's the same reason you can't access the counter variable in a `for` loop outside the `for` loop.

Comment: now I am getting "error: non-static variable amount cannot be referenced" and "int cannot be dereferenced"

Comment: So add the keyword `static` after the double. For future reference, you can find answers to a lot of these questions about the debugger just by Googling the error you get or reading the textbook your course is using.